# jquery ASP.Net "Invalid expression term '{'"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery in ASP.Net mvc 5 website project.

This is my code

```
function loadTableWorkshops() {

  @foreach (var item in Model) {

    var row = jQuery("<tr></tr>").append("<td>" + item.title + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td>");
    var deletebtn = jQuery("<a>Delete</a>").attr({
         "data-toggle": "modal",
         "data-target": "#myModal"})
       .addClass("delete")
       .click(function () { displayDeleteAlert(item.wid, item.title) });
    var detailsbtn = jQuery("<a>Details</a>").attr("href", "/TLCWS/myPlutonLocalhost/workshopDetails.php?wid=" + item.wid + "&wstitle=" + item.title)
        .addClass("details");

    ...

  } //foreach
} //function
```

the error that I receive is

```
CS1525: Invalid expression term '{'
```

and it references this line of code

```
var deletebtn = jQuery("<a>Delete</a>").attr({
```

I tried to initialize the `var deletebtn` in one line but the problem is still there. I am sure that jQuery is included properly in my project since it works fine in other places of the project and in the same file too.

Comment: You're putting jquery inside your c#

Comment: You cannot mix razor (server side code) with javascript (client side code) like that

Comment: I need to put it this way.. is there a work around to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@foreach .. {` the following statements are c# statements until the closing `}` - but you've put javascript/jquery statements there instead.

Without checking, you should be able to do:

```
function loadTableWorkshops() {

    @foreach (var item in Model) {

      // item is server-side so needs @item

    <text>
      var row = jQuery("<tr></tr>").append("<td>" + @item.title + "</td><td>" + @item.date + "</td>");
      var deletebtn = jQuery("<a>Delete</a>").attr({
          "data-toggle": "modal",
          "data-target": "#myModal"})
        .addClass("delete")
        .click(function () { displayDeleteAlert(@item.wid, @item.title) });
      var detailsbtn = jQuery("<a>Details</a>").attr("href", "/TLCWS/myPlutonLocalhost/workshopDetails.php?wid=" + @item.wid + "&wstitle=" + @item.title)
        .addClass("details");

      ...
    </text>

    } //foreach
}
```

but you might want to completely rethink how you are generating your dynamic html.

For example, you could convert your model to javascript first, then use pure js to manipulate it, eg:

```
function loadTableWorkshops() {

    var items = '@Model.ToString()';  // convert here, maybe use JSON if you haven't overridden ToString()

    items.each(function() {
      var item = this;
      var row = jQuery("<tr></tr>").append("<td>" + item.title + "</td><td>" + item.date + "</td>");
      var deletebtn = jQuery("<a>Delete</a>").attr({
          "data-toggle": "modal",
          "data-target": "#myModal"})
        .addClass("delete")
        .click(function () { displayDeleteAlert(item.wid, item.title) });
      var detailsbtn = jQuery("<a>Details</a>").attr("href", "/TLCWS/myPlutonLocalhost/workshopDetails.php?wid=" + item.wid + "&wstitle=" + item.title)
        .addClass("details");

      ...
    } //each
}
```

The key will be in how you convert `Model` to `items` - it's unlikely `ToString` will suffice, but should get you closer.